Undetected driver breaks down after third open url
I am doing some web scraping and I had to start using undetected chromedriver. The problem is that my code used to work with the normal chromedriver, but when using the undetected one it doesn't even execute it, but breaks down on the first/fourth url in the list. The driver.get doesn't get done, I just get a blank page in the chrome tab that keeps on loading until it end it.
Here is the simplified code:
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver

driver = uc.Chrome() -- this one doesn't work
driver = webdriver.Chrome() -- with this it works
driver = Driver(uc=True, incognito=True) -- using seleniumbase, doesn't work

initial_urls = \['http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1361-6595/aa97af', 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TPS.2009.2015323', 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.vacuum.2008.04.063', 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10582-006-0301-5', 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TPS.2014.2301734', 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TPS.2016.2598564', 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TPS.2011.2143433'\]

for url in initial_urls:
print(url)
driver.get(url)
print("I got it")

time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()

I tried using seleniumbase, checked the versions so that they are updated and created a virtual environment so that everything would be separated. I'm using python 3.12.5, in VSCode on a Macbook.
